# What do you call a matrix that has rows and columns of similar index summing up to same numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, network-flow

I'm building a flow matrix of a graph and I came to realize that my matrix of size $ N \times N $ has this simple property:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}{A_{ni} } = \sum_{n=1}^{N}{A_{in} } $$
for $ i \in [1, N] $.
further properties:

- Rows and columns add up to different numbers, so I excluded `Stochastic Matrix`
- Definitely not `symmetric`

I'm not sure if there is a term for it. It seems to be one-normalization step away from being left-stochastic or right-stochastic. It also seems to be generalized form of `double stochastic matrix` where the sum is not the same and is not necessarily equal to one.

Intuitively, the property meant to capture the fact that number of people coming to a node is equal to number of people leaving that node, therefore, none of the nodes is a `sink` nor a `source`.

Comment: So, the sun along the $i$th row equals the sun along the $i$th column?  Is that the property?